# KQL query in Sentinel to pull first and last activity in a day for user

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I need help to pull out data for first and last activity for a specific user. For example to see if the first activity was Microsoft teams and when. And when was the last activity and which one

I tried this and it gives all of the activity. I can't figure out the way so that the query would project only one first and last activity. The actual ones.

```
OfficeActivity
| where UserId == 'UserId'
| summarize FirstActivity = min(TimeGenerated), LastActivity = max(TimeGenerated) by TimeGenerated, Application, Operation
| join 
(
    OfficeActivity
    | summarize FirstActivity2 = min(TimeGenerated), LastActivity2 = max(TimeGenerated) by TimeGenerated, Application, OfficeWorkload
)
on TimeGenerated
| project FirstActivity, LastActivity, Application, OfficeWorkload, Operation
| sort by FirstActivity asc
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try using the [`arg_max()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction) and [`arg_min()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-min-aggfunction) aggregation functions, or the [`top`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/topoperator) operator

for example:

```
let base =
    OfficeActivity 
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
    | where UserId == 'UserId'
;
union
(base | top 1 by TimeGenerated asc),
(base | top 1 by TimeGenerated desc)
```

or

```
let base =
    OfficeActivity 
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
    | where UserId == 'UserId'
;
union
(base | summarize arg_min(TimeGenerated, *)),
(base | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *))
```

or, if you only needs the timestamps and not the rest of the columns:

```
let base =
    OfficeActivity 
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
    | where UserId == 'UserId'
;
let min_dt = toscalar(base | summarize min(TimeGenerated);
let max_dt = toscalar(base | summarize max(TimeGenerated);
print min_dt, max_dt
```

Comment: L
I tried this one
**let base =
    OfficeActivity 
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
    | where UserId == 'UserId'
;
union
(base | summarize arg_min(TimeGenerated, *)),
(base | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *))**

and it is ok. 
Can you give me please a suggestion how to filter it by date. What would be the best way to do it.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "filter it by date"

Comment: I managed to get result on a certain date. Now I have an issue where it doesn't show the correct times if I remove one line.
If I remove that line, then it shows exchange in OfficeWorkload log but wrong time.
If I leave the line, it shows only Teams, SP, OD but correct time.